# Is there a way to authenticate vpn using SMS

Tags: windows, vpn, authentication

I would like to implement VPN access to our company servers (Windows/ADS). The problem is that we have confidential intellectual property we want to protect, and we are afraid that engineers are not the most creative people for creating hard passwords.

We use a sonicwall firewall.

Is there a way to demand double authentication to have VPN access? I mean, when a certain user tries to log-in via VPN, the VPN server sends an SMS (or via smartphone app - android or iphone) to the user that needs to be entered to gain full VPN access?

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed duo two factor authentication and have been very happy with it. It can be configured to use a smartphone app with push notifications/otp or sms or phone calls. I set it up across my linux systems but there are integrations for widows and a variety of other devices/applications.

Comment: Duo Security is awesome +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this?](http://www.brainbump.net/two-factor-authentication-for-cisco-vpn-solutions/)

One-Time Password via SMS authentication to Cisco ASA VPN End-to-End Full Configuration including OTP Server is covered in detail [here](http://www.packetwisdom.com/CiscoSecureACSProduct.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions that provide two factor authentication and sending the second factor via SMS.

The important question is, which can be integrated into your sonic wall the best. 
Hopefully your sonicwall is capable of authenticating the user via RADIUS. Most solutions also implement the RADIUS protocol.